# How to control file download (choose directory, filename, switch automatic download on/off) for Chrome?

Tags: c#, google-chrome

There is the same example copy-pasted all over the internet, but firstly, I found examples for Java which I could find a way to make it work for C# so far and I wonder if that code is still working at all or is it something outdated already?
I found stuff like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68808757/choose-directory-to-download-files-with-selenium-in-chrome) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60292290/rselenium-chrome-how-to-set-download-directory-file-download-error)

Example of my attempts in the code:

```
string downloadFilepath = "D:/test";
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
Dictionary<string, object> chromePrefs = new Dictionary<string, object>();
chromePrefs.Add("profile.default_content_settings.popups", 0);
chromePrefs.Add("download.default_directory", downloadFilepath);
//options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", chromePrefs); // doesn't work since ChromeOptions doesn't contain method setExperimentalOption or anything similar
options.AddArguments("prefs", chromePrefs.ToString()); // doesn't work neither (just was trying something relatively logical)
IWebDriver webDriver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not sure what your actual question is. If you are having a problem, please [edit] your question to include a [repro].

Comment: You can find some examples in provided links. And I didn't provide any code for C# because I didn't find a way to make it work in C# right now. Just attempts to copy-paste code and edit it using intelliscence of visual studio, which didn't find anything similar. Also googling anything similar for C# didn't help neither. Copy-pasting code from provided links doesn't seem to be a good thing to do.

Comment: Copying and pasting is a start. If you include the code you tried in your question, we might be able to help you.

Comment: I didn't save that code, because it didn't even look like something that could possibly work because of missing method from example. But I've reproduced the code as I remember it.

Comment: And what error are you getting? What is the stack trace?

Comment: If applying code from above there's no error, just download directory doesn't change.

Comment: *"there's no error, just download directory doesn't change"* --- I'm not sure what you mean? Can you explain more?

Comment: I don't understand what to explain. I want to change download directory. It doesn't change after applying code from above.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# Set default download directory chrome WebDriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35446893/3092298)

Comment: I removed the [tag:specflow] tag and changed the question title, since this has nothing to do with SpecFlow.

Comment: It does. Thank you so much. ) Why didn't you write an answer?

Comment: That other question I linked to is a duplicate.

Comment: Should I delete my question to avoid duplicates?

Comment: You can mark your question as a duplicate. Nothing working with that. Sometimes duplicates are phrased differently, and might capture someone else's search terms in Google. Duplicates are not bad, in my opinion.